# Django Admin intercept onchange event of a field and make an action

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-admin

In my django project i would clear a field value every time another select field have an onChange event.
I have an add form like thisone:

[image]

every time Template field change (onChange), Test Case field have to become blank.

How can i do this in a django admin add or edit page?

So many thanks in advance

Comment: If you want it reflect immediately without reload the page then you should use JavaScript to listen onChange event and reset the value of other field. If you okay with that, I can give you an answer using js

Comment: ok, so many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event can also be set in the modelform meta widgets dict;

```
class ReceiptsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Receipts
        fields = []
        widgets = {
            'partner_id': forms.Select(attrs={'onchange': 'this.form.submit();'})
        }
```

Answer (score 9):

You could [customize Admin asset definition](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-asset-definitions) and use JavaScript/jQuery to handle your problem. Here is an example:

**admin.py**

```
class TestCaseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        js = (
            'js/admin.js',   # inside app static folder
        )

admin.site.register(TestCase, TestCaseAdmin)
```

**js/admin.js**

```
if (!$) {
    // Need this line because Django also provided jQuery and namespaced as django.jQuery
    $ = django.jQuery;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select[name='template']").change(function() {
        $("select['test_case']").val('');
    });
});
```

- `template`, `test_case` are field name on your model

Comment: @abnerh69, I didn't get your idea. Why it should be "class Media"? The reason why I use `class Meta` because that's a feature in Django which allows us to set metadata for other classes

Comment: It's because Django (versions 1.8 to 3.0) documentation at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-asset-definitions.  But your answer helps me a lot.  Just change Meta for Media.